# Chain rule in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, calculus, derivative

I'm trying some basic practice with SymPy. I would like to take a second derivative symbolically of a function in rectangular coordinates with respect to the radius parameter in polar coordinates.

I'd like a nice chain rule symbolic expression where it calculates what it can and leaves unevaluated what can't be simplified further.

```
from sympy import *
init_session()
x, y, r, t = symbols('x y r t') # r (radius), t (angle theta)
f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
g = f(x,y)
x = r * cos(t)
y = r* sin(t)
Derivative(g,r, 2).doit()
```

This code yields `0`. Is there a way to get a symbolic representation of the answer, rather than 0?

Comment: So what is a question?

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:**
Your commands are out of order.

**Long answer:**

```
x, y, r, t = symbols('x y r t') # r (radius), t (angle theta)
f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
g = f(x,y)
```

Now `x,y` are Symbols, `f` is a Function and `g` is an applied Function i.e. the symbols `x,y` applied to `f` as `f(x,y)`.

```
x = r * cos(t)
y = r* sin(t)
```

Now you redefine `x` and `y` as expressions of `r` and `t`. This does not affect `g` in the slightest!

```
Derivative(g,r, 2).doit()
```

Now you derive `g` wrt `r`. As `g` is still defined via the initial symbols `x,y` it does not depend on `r`, thus the derivative is zero.

To achieve what you want use this:

```
from sympy import *
r, t = symbols('r t') # r (radius), t (angle theta)
f = symbols('f', cls=Function)
x = r* cos(t)
y = r* sin(t)
g = f(x,y)
Derivative(g,r, 2).doit()
```

I also dropped all unnecessary Symbol definitions.

Comment: Cool. In the result of `diff(g,r,2).simplify()` it seems to be replacing x and y with $\xi_1$  and $\xi_2$ and then subbing them out with their values in terms of $r$ and $t$. Is there a way for it to keep them in terms of x and y?

Comment: @Hatshepsut if you want an explicit symbol named "x", use `symbols('x')`. If you just want the name "x" to refer to some other expression in the code use `x = r*cos(t)`. See also http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html.

Comment: @PeterE :  what if I want to replace f(x) by sin(x) ?  I have been trying and nothing works. The replacement is on the output of yourr "Derivative..."  line.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. If `f` is defined as `f: x->sin(x)` you can simply define `g` directly: `g = sin(x)`.

Comment: @PeteE :  I opened a new case on this. Please check the link next :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77558421/substitute-would-not-work-when-using-chain-rule-in-sympy