# substitute would not work when using chain rule in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following `SymPy` script

```
from sympy import Function, symbols, diff, cos
x, y = symbols('x y') 
f, g = symbols("f g", cls=Function)
g = g(x)
f =  f(x + g) # function composition here
dfdx = diff(f,x)
dfdx
```

This produces:

[image: result of the previous code]

I want to replace f(x) by cos(x)  (or if you prefer f(xi_1) = cos(xi_1), whatever works).
But this does not work.

Here is what I am doing:

```
dfdx.subs([(f, cos(x))])
```

The result is exactly the same expression. Nothing changes.

I also tried

```
dfdx.replace(f, cos(x))
```

Again, the result is exactly the same. Nothing changes.
How can I get cos(x) instead of f(x) in my expressions, after substitution?

Comment: Why are you reassigning `f`?  Is `f` still a symbol after `f=f(x+g)` assignment.  In sympy be careful about treating `f` as a python variable and as a sympy symbol.

Comment: I can assign ``f`` to any analytic function, right? could be ``sin(x), cos(x), exp(x)`` or anything.  In the case ``f=f(x+g)``, if ``f(x)=sin(x)`` then ``f(x + g)= sin(x + g(x))`` . It is interesting that for ``g(x)`` it works fine. Check the line ``dfdx.subs([(g, cos(x))]) ``

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking more along the line of:

```
In [46]: f1=f(x+g(x))
```

I am using `g(x)` in this expression, rather than your `g=g(x)`.

```
In [47]: dfdx = diff(f1,x)    
In [48]: dfdx
Out[48]: 
(Derivative(g(x), x) + 1)*Subs(Derivative(f(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, x + g(x))
    
In [50]: dfdx.subs({f:cos})
Out[50]: 
(Derivative(g(x), x) + 1)*Subs(Derivative(cos(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, x + g(x))

In [51]: dfdx.subs({g:cos})
Out[51]: 
(Derivative(cos(x), x) + 1)*Subs(Derivative(f(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, x + cos(x))
```

You are trying to do

```
In [52]: dfdx.subs({f1:cos})
Out[52]: 
(Derivative(g(x), x) + 1)*Subs(Derivative(f(_xi_1), _xi_1), _xi_1, x + g(x))
```

Comment: you got it right, thanks!. Still this is confusing to me. I need to study your right solution.

Comment: Another thing that make a difference is that you say ``{f:cos}``, while I was saying ``{ f:cos(x)}``   .  Removing the argument from cos makes a big difference.